# Why does a vector value stored in an integer give different results?

Tags: c++11, vector

I have very recently started using vectors in C++.The purpose of the program I am trying to write is to determine the first missing positive number. Given an input array `A : [ -9, 12, -1, 0, 1 ]` the expected output is `2`. I coded it -

```
int Solution::firstMissingPositive(vector<int> &A)
{
    std::sort(A.begin(),A.end());    //sorting vector

    bool Negative=false;
    int flag;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<A.size();++i)
    {
        if(A[i]<=0)
        {
            Negative=true;
            std::cout<<"\nwe found a -ve number or 0";
        }
        else if( (A[i]>0) && (A[i+1]!=A[i]+1) )
        {
            Negative=false;
            std::cout<<"\ncomparing @ ="<<i<<" which = "<<A[i];
            std::cout<<"\ncomparing @ ="<<i+1<<" which = "<<A[i+1];

            flag=A[i]+1; //The faulty statement

            std::cout<<"\n\n missing number(A[i]+1) @ ="<<A[i]+1;
            std::cout<<"\n\n missing number(flag) @ ="<<flag;
            break;
        }

    }
//do something more
}
```

With this output -

```
-9 -1 0 1 12 
we found a -ve number or 0
we found a -ve number or 0
we found a -ve number or 0
comparing @ =3 which = 1
comparing @ =4 which = 12

missing number(A[i]+1) @ =2

missing number(flag) @ =20
```

I found this interesting because, to me, it looks like I cannot use an integer to store the value of a vector.

- Trying to debug it I found changing the flag assignment to `flag = A[i]+2` makes the resultant print `30`.
- I've read other questions on SO where it suggests using `vector.at(i)` instead of the `[]` operator as a better practice. Changing this does not reflect any change for my code.
- Changing `flag` to `vector<int>` gives me a dirty error which I'm not sure about.

Isn't `A[i]+1` syntactically equivalent to an integer value? And if it is, why can I not store it?

Comment: `A[i+1]` is an out-of-bounds access

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Only for the last iteration, and with that input it shouldn't be hitting it.

Comment: I suspect that you or whatever script you are using to run this is printing a `0` afterwards, possibly for the return code. Try printing a `'\n'` after you print `flag`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Should I edit that to `else if( (A[i]>0) && (A[i+1]!=A[i]+1) && (i!=A.size()-1))` ?

Comment: I dont have access to the script running this code. I'm using an online compiler. And printing `\n` fixes it. Thanks @T.C. So sorry for the bother. Please close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducing your code to an MCVE quickly demonstrates that the problem is with your output formatting, putting the "\n" at the beginning of the statement is an uncommon practice for precisely this reason. You're not seeing 20, what you're seeing is the "2" from flag followed by a zero printed elsewhere.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void solve(std::vector<int>& A)
{
    std::sort(A.begin(),A.end());    //sorting vector

    bool Negative=false;
    int flag;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<A.size();++i)
    {
        if(A[i]<=0)
        {
            Negative=true;
            std::cout<<"we found a -ve number or 0\n";
        }
        else if( (A[i]>0) && (A[i+1]!=A[i]+1) )
        {
            Negative=false;
            std::cout<<"comparing @ ="<<i<<" which = "<<A[i]<<'\n';
            std::cout<<"comparing @ ="<<i+1<<" which = "<<A[i+1]<<'\n';

            flag=A[i]+1; //The faulty statement

            std::cout<<"missing number(A[i]+1) @ ="<<A[i]+1<<'\n';
            std::cout<<"missing number(flag) @ ="<<flag<<'\n';
            break;
        }

    }
//do something more
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A { -9, 12, -1, 0, 1 };
    solve(A);
    std::cout << "and we're done\n";
}
```

Output (see http://ideone.com/zb9fNX)

```
we found a -ve number or 0
we found a -ve number or 0
we found a -ve number or 0
comparing @ =3 which = 1
comparing @ =4 which = 12
missing number(A[i]+1) @ =2
missing number(flag) @ =2
and we're done
```

I should also point out that your test for "A[i+1]" will lead to an out of bounds array access if it ever tries to read the last element in the array. You should change

```
for(i=0;i<A.size();++i)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<A.size() - 1;++i)
```

or more conventially,

```
for(i=1;i<A.size();++i)
```

and use "A[i-1]" instead of "A[i+1]" to fetch the previous value.

For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void solve(std::vector<int>& A)
{
    std::sort(A.begin(),A.end());    //sorting vector

    int expected = 0;
    int missing = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < A.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] <= 0) {
            std::cout << "we found " << A[i] << "\n";
            continue;
        }

        if (A[i-1] <= 0) {
            expected = 1;
        } else {
            expected = A[i-1] + 1;
        }
        if (A[i] == expected)
            continue;

        std::cout << "A[" << i-1 << "] = " << A[i-1] << '\n';
        std::cout << "expecting " << expected << '\n';
        std::cout << "A[" << i << "] = " << A[i] << '\n';

        missing = expected;         
        std::cout << "missing number: " << expected << '\n';

        break;
    }
//do something more
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A { -9, 12, -1, 0, 1 };
    solve(A);
    std::cout << "and we're done\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/AIw4oU

Comment: Thanks for telling me what practices to employ! Really helps.